# Create Page In Confluence Via Rest API using Java

Tags: java, rest, confluence, confluence-rest-api

Does anyone have any examples on how to create a page/wiki entry in Confluence using Confluence's RESTful API?  I'm trying to write something in Java that can do this.

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you, I already checked the documentation online but I couldn't find any examples **THAT USE JAVA** in the Confluence REST API.  That's why I posted on here.

Regardless, I think I figured it out:

```
    import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
    import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
    import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;
    import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
    import java.net.URLEncoder;

    /**
     * Creates a Confluence wiki page via the RESTul API
     * using an HTTP Post command.
     */
    public class ConfluenceRestApi2CreateEntry {

        //private static final String BASE_URL = "http://localhost:1990/confluence";
        private static final String BASE_URL = "https://<context>.atlassian.net/wiki";
        private static final String USERNAME = "username";
        private static final String PASSWORD = "password";
        private static final String ENCODING = "utf-8";

        public static String createContentRestUrl()throws UnsupportedEncodingException
        {
            return String.format("%s/rest/api/content/?&os_authType=basic&os_username=%s&os_password=%s", BASE_URL, URLEncoder.encode(USERNAME, ENCODING), URLEncoder.encode(PASSWORD, ENCODING));

        }

        public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception
        {
            String wikiPageTitle = "My Awesome Page";
            String wikiPage = "<h1>Things That Are Awesome</h1><ul><li>Birds</li><li>Mammals</li><li>Decapods</li></ul>";
            String wikiSpace = "JOUR";
            String labelToAdd = "awesome_stuff";
            int parentPageId = 9994250;


            JSONObject newPage = defineConfluencePage(wikiPageTitle,
                    wikiPage,
                    wikiSpace,
                    labelToAdd,
                    parentPageId);

            createConfluencePageViaPost(newPage);

        }

        public static void createConfluencePageViaPost(JSONObject newPage) throws Exception
        {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

            // Send update request
            HttpEntity pageEntity = null;

            try
            {
                //2016-12-18 - StirlingCrow: Left off here.  Was finally able to get the post command to work
                //I can begin testing adding more data to the value stuff (see above)
                HttpPost postPageRequest = new HttpPost(createContentRestUrl());

                StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(newPage.toString(), ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
                postPageRequest.setEntity(entity);

                HttpResponse postPageResponse = client.execute(postPageRequest);
                pageEntity = postPageResponse.getEntity();

                System.out.println("Push Page Request returned " + postPageResponse.getStatusLine().toString());
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println(IOUtils.toString(pageEntity.getContent()));
            }
            finally
            {
                EntityUtils.consume(pageEntity);
            }
        }

        public static JSONObject defineConfluencePage(String pageTitle,
                                                      String wikiEntryText,
                                                      String pageSpace,
                                                      String label,
                                                      int parentPageId) throws JSONException
        {
            //This would be the command in Python (similar to the example
            //in the Confluence example:
            //
            //curl -u <username>:<password> -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{
            // "type":"page",
            // "title":"My Awesome Page",
            // "ancestors":[{"id":9994246}],
            // "space":{"key":"JOUR"},
            // "body":
            //        {"storage":
            //                   {"value":"<h1>Things That Are Awesome</h1><ul><li>Birds</li><li>Mammals</li><li>Decapods</li></ul>",
            //                    "representation":"storage"}
            //        },
            // "metadata":
            //             {"labels":[
            //                        {"prefix":"global",
            //                        "name":"journal"},
            //                        {"prefix":"global",
            //                        "name":"awesome_stuff"}
            //                       ]
            //             }
            // }'
            // http://localhost:8080/confluence/rest/api/content/ | python -mjson.tool

            JSONObject newPage = new JSONObject();

            // "type":"page",
            // "title":"My Awesome Page"
            newPage.put("type","page");
            newPage.put("title", pageTitle);

            // "ancestors":[{"id":9994246}],
            JSONObject parentPage = new JSONObject();
            parentPage.put("id",parentPageId);

            JSONArray parentPageArray = new JSONArray();
            parentPageArray.put(parentPage);

            newPage.put("ancestors", parentPageArray);

            // "space":{"key":"JOUR"},
            JSONObject spaceOb = new JSONObject();
            spaceOb.put("key",pageSpace);
            newPage.put("space", spaceOb);

            // "body":
            //        {"storage":
            //                   {"value":"<p><h1>Things That Are Awesome</h1><ul><li>Birds</li><li>Mammals</li><li>Decapods</li></ul></p>",
            //                    "representation":"storage"}
            //        },
            JSONObject jsonObjects = new JSONObject();

            jsonObjects.put("value", wikiEntryText);
            jsonObjects.put("representation","storage");

            JSONObject storageObject = new JSONObject();
            storageObject.put("storage", jsonObjects);

            newPage.put("body", storageObject);


            //LABELS
            // "metadata":
            //             {"labels":[
            //                        {"prefix":"global",
            //                        "name":"journal"},
            //                        {"prefix":"global",
            //                        "name":"awesome_stuff"}
            //                       ]
            //             }
            JSONObject prefixJsonObject1 = new JSONObject();
            prefixJsonObject1.put("prefix","global");
            prefixJsonObject1.put("name","journal");
            JSONObject prefixJsonObject2 = new JSONObject();
            prefixJsonObject2.put("prefix","global");
            prefixJsonObject2.put("name",label);

            JSONArray prefixArray = new JSONArray();
            prefixArray.put(prefixJsonObject1);
            prefixArray.put(prefixJsonObject2);

            JSONObject labelsObject = new JSONObject();
            labelsObject.put("labels", prefixArray);

            newPage.put("metadata",labelsObject);

            return newPage;
        }
    }
```

Here's a project in GitHub that I created that also has an example of simply pulling wiki page entry using Java:

- https://github.com/stirlingcrow/Confluence-AccessRestApiWithJava

Answer (score 1):

What about using the official REST client?
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.atlassian.confluence/confluence-rest-client

I'm not able to find any documentation on how to use it, tho.

Comment: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Confluence-questions/Confluence-Java-REST-Client-library/qaq-p/755162